# How to send as many http get to the same host from the same client in Java

Tags: http

I must apologise for asking a very general questions on sending http get using Java. 
(The through put could be affected by many things.)

I am asked to investigate how many http get requests from a single  client to a single remote host across the internet in Java.

Lets assume the remote host can handle as many http get requests as the client sends to it.

Basically, my approach is to run the following piece of Java code in as many threads as possible.
private void send(int i) throws IOException {

```
    final String urlStr = String.format(urlTemplate, host, i);

    URL urlObj = new URL(urlStr);

    HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) urlObj.openConnection();
    con.setRequestMethod("GET");
    con.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", USER_AGENT);
    con.getResponseCode();

    con.disconnect();

}
```

If I have ten or more threads I get 
java.net.NoRouteToHostException: Cannot assign requested address

After some googling, I found setting /proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_tw_reuse
to 1, helps to get ride of the above  NoRouteToHostException, with 20 threads.

With 20 threads, now i could send about 2000 http get requests from a single client to a remote host.

Is there any other changes in the client side that would increase the no of http get requests that I could sent from a single client ?

Thanks in advance for any assistance !

Shing

Comment: Each time you resolve a bottleneck, you hit another. It's a never dnding game.

Comment: Sounds like what you're looking for is a DoS attack.